# Wrapper not displaying content inline correctly

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox

I´m having a little problem with my website that I have to finish for a school project. I've got php code inside a wrapper that I´m trying to display inline witch it does now but the content just gets smaller and doesn't really stack.
The content in the wrapper repeats and is supposed to be next to each other until there aint no space left and then it should go under the first one. I hope you understand what I mean :). Any help would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
 <section class="wrapper">
<?php
  foreach ($armbond as $entry)
  {
    echo "<div class='box'> " . "name: " . $entry[0] . "." . " " . "<br> inforamtion: " .  $entry[2] . "." . '<br> <img src="' . $entry[1] . '" style="width:304p"' .'">'. " " . "<br> price: " .  $entry[3] . "</div> ";
  }
?>
</section>`
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-wrap;
}

.box{
  background: silver;
  margin:2px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}`
```

Comment: show us the rendered html

Comment: Could this be part of the problem? `style="width:304p"` missing an `x` there.

Comment: Also `inforamtion` should probably be `information`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex-flow: row wrap;` there is no `row-wrap`.

Read more here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-flow/

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box{
  background: silver;
  margin:2px;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class='box'>name:zzzz
    <br> inforamtion: xxxx
    <br> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff" style="width:300px">
    <br> price:111111
 </div>
  <div class='box'>name:zzzz
    <br> inforamtion: xxxx
    <br> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff" style="width:300px">
    <br> price:111111
 </div>
  <div class='box'>name:zzzz
    <br> inforamtion: xxxx
    <br> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff" style="width:300px">
    <br> price:111111
 </div>
  <div class='box'>name:zzzz
    <br> inforamtion: xxxx
    <br> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff" style="width:300px">
    <br> price:111111
 </div>
</section>
```